# Geopandas import error

Tags: python, import, conda, forge, geopandas

I am using jupyter notebook and Anaconda 2 environment to run scripts.
I recently installed geopandas package.
The geopandas package is listed as under conda list:
geopandas                 0.2.1                    py27_3    conda-forge

When I try to import geopandas the following error occurs:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c9ee6bd24dbc> in <module>()
----> 1 import geopandas

C:\Users\Kerem Turgutlu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.pyc in <module>()
      2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
      3 
----> 4 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
      5 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis
      6 from geopandas.tools import sjoin

C:\Users\Kerem Turgutlu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in <module>()
      1 import os
      2 
----> 3 import fiona
      4 import numpy as np
      5 from shapely.geometry import mapping

C:\Users\Kerem Turgutlu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py in <module>()
     67 from six import string_types
     68 
---> 69 from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
     70 from fiona._drivers import driver_count, GDALEnv
     71 from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers

C:\Users\Kerem Turgutlu\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py in <module>()
      7 
      8 from fiona import compat
----> 9 from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
     10 from fiona.ogrext import Session, WritingSession
     11 from fiona.ogrext import (

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Thank You

Comment: The answer may solve your problem as well.

Comment: How is `fiona` listed in `conda list`? Is it also installed from conda-forge?